# OpenSSH upgrade library vs header mismatch

Tags: ubuntu, configure, openssh, ldflags

I am installing a newer version of openssh on to an ubuntu server (raring 13.04)

I have set       `export LDFLAGS="-I/usr/lib-I/usr/local/lib"`

And when running my `./configure` statement which is

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --exec_prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib/openssh
--sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --datadir=/usr/share/sshd --with-md5-passwords 
--with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd
```

The output ends:

```
.....
checking OpenSSL header version... 1000105f (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
checking OpenSSL library version... 1000103f (OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012)
checking whether OpenSSL's headers match the library... no
configure: error: Your OpenSSL headers do not match your
library. Check config.log for details.
```

I tried a tip suggesting changing LDFLAGS to

`export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/libssl.so -/usr/lib/libcrypto.so"`

to force use of one library

But then when I run the ./configure command I get

```
.........
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/sas/openssh-6.2p2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Dose any one have any further thoughts?

Comment: `-I` should go in `CFLAGS`, not in `LDFLAGS`, the linker does not use `include` statements so when it gets to linking it's too late to change include path. `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/libssl.so -/usr/lib/libcrypto.so"` is also a bit messed up, it should probably be plain; `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"` since `-L` just takes a path for the compiler to look for libraries, not an absolute path to an actual library.

Comment: Cheers- I have tried several variations of LDFLAGS statements including just "-L/usr/lib" the one you note was from another person with the same issue on another site it worked for them - but not for me

Comment: Cheers- I have tried several variations of LDFLAGS statements including just "-L/usr/lib" the one you note was from another person with the same issue on another site it worked for them - but not for me      Regarding CFLAGS I thought it was CPPLFAGS so I have tried various CPPFLAGS= statments alone and with LDFLAGS Including CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include"  and CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include"       I have tried the following which I think is your suggestion CFLAGS="-I/usr/include"  and when that did not work CFLAGS="-I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include"  Any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty easy. A lot of people face this problem, so i thought of sharing how i solved it hoping it helps someone out there especially with the issue with the "heart bleed bug". If you have this trying to compile openssl for example:

```
checking OpenSSL header version... 1000107f (OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014)
checking OpenSSL library version... 9080ef (OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013)
checking whether OpenSSL's headers match the library... no
configure: error: Your OpenSSL headers do not match your
library.
```

### Solution:

1. Locate the openssl tarball and rebuild it as shown below.

   ```
   tar xvfz /usr/src/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz   (IF YOU DID THIS BEFORE GO TO NEXT STEP)
   cd /usr/src/openssl-1.0.1g/  
   ./config –prefix=/usr/local –openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared
   make clean
   make
   make test
   make install
   openssl version
   echo "/usr/local/ssl/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
   ldconfig –v
   ```
2. Recompile openssh

   ```
   tar xvfz /usr/src/openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz   (IF YOU DID THIS BEFORE GO TO NEXT STEP)
   cd /usr/src/openssh-6.6p1/
   ./configure
   make
   make install
   ```
3. Verify installation and restart the sshd daemon

   ```
   ssh –V

   OpenSSH_6.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014 (this should be your display)

   /etc/rc.d/rc.sshd restart
   ```

you may have to log out of your ssh session and log back in, then do `ssh -V` again.